# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes error in MinMaxScaler

Tags: python, pandas, lstm

I am developing a prediction model in Python, based on a historical data of previous 45 quarters starting from q-1 of 2010. I am using LSTM for prediction. While trying to implement the following line:

```
y_perd_future = scaler.inverse_transform(forecast_copies)[:,0]
X = X.copy()
    936             if self.with_std: 
    937                 X *= self.scale_
    938             if self.with_mean:
    939                 X += self.mean_

 ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (31,630,3) (32,) (31,630,3)
```

Please dont give me examples of small self created arrays. I am looking for advice in context of large data.

Humble Regards

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise on where exactly it fails? Also the size of the arrays doesn't really matter for this example is is about having them aligned in their shapes.

Comment: Dear Simon, it fails at "y_perd_future = scaler.inverse_transform(forecast_copies)[:,0]" line of code, or in other words when i try to inverse transform the predicted values.

Answer (score 1):

I have found easiest solution , instantiate two scaler one for target variable and other independent variable , simple.

```
feature = X_train.columns<br>
xscaler = MinMaxScaler()<br>
X_train[feature] = xscaler.fit_transform(X_train[feature])<br>
X_val[feature] = xscaler.transform(X_val[feature])<br>
X_test[feature] = xscaler.transform(X_test[feature])<br>

yscaler = MinMaxScaler()<br>
y_train = yscaler.fit_transform(y_train.values.reshape(-1,1))<br>
y_val = yscaler.transform(y_val.values.reshape(-1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that one tensor has 31 elements (31, 630, 3) while the other 32 (32,) and thus it cannot be broadcasted. At least one dimension must match.

Comment: Dear Flavio, thank you for your answer. I am struggling really hard at how to match these arrays. Please guide me i am new to multivariate time series analysis

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is what is scaled first,
First of all always scale , target and features separately
I always scale independent variables first & then scale target variable later,
I don't know why but MinMaxscaler or any scaling technique takes in to account what is scaled last.
After prediction you can use `inverse_transform` fro ex.

```
pressure = scaler.inverse_transform(y_train_pred_lr.values.reshape(-1,1))
print(pressure)
```

Better to scale target & features separately, scale target after independent variable
Hope this solves your problem, let me know if it does.

If you scale features first & scale target later, this will give you broadcast error

Answer (score 0):

Better to use two different instance of scaling for example, 'scaler' for the independent variables and 'scaler1' for dependent i.e target variable.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32792651)